# My 1st attempt with method in Java: doesn't work

Tags: java, methods

I need to put this `(Math.random() * 37)` into a working method.
This is what I made with a tutorial but there is an error on the first row "identifier expected". What is wrong with this code? Please help.

```
public static double hodKulickou (double) 
{
    return (Math.random() * 37);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend getting a book on java before you do tutorials. Learn how the language works and tutorials will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right. You should consider understanding the principles behind your methods declaration.

In your case you did not provide a local name for the method to assign to the double value it was expecting. Read on if you're interested in understanding the principles as I understand them.

Each word in the method declaration serves a purpose. From left to right.

public - means this method can be accessed publicly and not just by code in that class.

static - means the methods is static and belongs to that class, is not a object member.

void - means the methods does not return any value.
yourmethod name - any name you see fit.

Now the interesting part. The method parameters. These are the values you may pass into the method. In the paramaters you include the type and a name for the value.

eg: methodName(int anInteger)

This means the method can expect an integer type to be passed to is and the method will call that integer anInteger for use within it's body. For whatever purpose you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a name to the double parameter of your method.

```
public static double hodKulickou (double name) {
   return (Math.random() * 37); 
}
```

Of course, since you are not using the double parameter, you can just remove it :

```
public static double hodKulickou () {
   return (Math.random() * 37); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you really followed the instructions of the tutorial ? You must provid an identifier to your parameters. That's exactly what the error message tells you btw.

```
public static double hodKulickou (double identifier) { 
     return (Math.random() * 37); 
}
```

However, you pass a parameter to your function but don't use it so actually it should be :

```
public static double hodKulickou () { 
     return (Math.random() * 37); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, since you don't use the parameter, you can omit it:

```
public static double hodKulickou () {   // <-- skipped
     return (Math.random() * 37); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method doesn't appear to need a parameter, this

```
 public static double hodKulickou (double)
```

should be

```
 public static double hodKulickou ()
```

or

```
 public static double hodKulickou (int val) { return (Math.random() * val); }
```

if you want to pass the "37" in.